# 401 Unauthorized when calling Web API using IdentityServer3

Tags: oauth-2.0, identityserver3

I'm trying to set up a simple example using IdentityServer3 with the Client Credential flow. The example contains a console client calling a Web API resource with a token recieved from the IdentityServer. The Web API and IdentityServer is hosted in IIS.

I manage to get the token from the IdentityServer using:

```
  var client = new TokenClient(
            "https://machine+domain/WebHostedId3/connect/token",
            "client",
            "secret");
```

but when I try calling the Web API using:

```
 var client = new HttpClient();

 client.SetBearerToken(token);

 var response = client.GetStringAsync("http://localhost/WebHostedApi/api/products").Result;
```

I recevie a 401 (Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).

The IdentityServer is set up as follows:

```
public class Clients
{
    public static List<Client> Get()
    {
        return new List<Client>
        {
            new Client
            {
                ClientName = "Client Credentials Flow Client",
                Enabled = true,
                ClientId = "client",
                AccessTokenType = AccessTokenType.Reference,
                ClientSecrets = new List<Secret>
                {
                    new Secret("secret".Sha256())
                },

                Flow = Flows.ClientCredentials,

                AllowedScopes = new List<string>
                {
                    "api"
                }
            }
        };
    }
}

public class Scopes
{
    public static IEnumerable<Scope> Get()
    {
        return new[]
            {
                new Scope
                {
                    Name = "api",
                    DisplayName = "API Scope",
                    Type = ScopeType.Resource,
                    Emphasize = false
                }
            };
    }
}

 public class Startup
 {
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
    {
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .WriteTo.Trace(outputTemplate: "{Timestamp} [{Level}] ({Name}){NewLine} {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}")
            .CreateLogger();

        var factory = new IdentityServerServiceFactory()
            .UseInMemoryUsers(new System.Collections.Generic.List<InMemoryUser>())
                    .UseInMemoryClients(Clients.Get())
                    .UseInMemoryScopes(Scopes.Get());

        var options = new IdentityServerOptions
        {
            Factory = factory,
        };

        appBuilder.UseIdentityServer(options);
    }
}
```

The Web API:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static HttpConfiguration Register()
    {
        var config = new HttpConfiguration();

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
           name: "DefaultRouting",
           routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
           defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
           );

        // require authentication for all controllers
        config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());

        return config;
    }
}

public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .WriteTo.Trace(outputTemplate: "{Timestamp} [{Level}] ({Name}){NewLine} {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}")
            .CreateLogger();

        app.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(
            new IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions
            {
                Authority = "machine+domain:443",
                ValidationMode = ValidationMode.ValidationEndpoint,
                RequiredScopes = new[] { "api" }
            });

        app.UseWebApi(WebApiConfig.Register());
    }
}
```

The certificate used for SSL is created using the IIS Create Self-Signed Certificate function and connected to the https binding for the IdentityServer. Except for the "Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized)" exception I can't find any more details. The logs from IdentityServer looks good. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I'm experiencing the same problem but can't find answers that work for me anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is very late reply. Try to update all nugets, especially Newtonsoft.Json to 8.0.3

Comment: No dice for me, upgrading nugets did nothing.

Comment: you have updated Newtonsoft.Json to 8.0.3 (or 8.0.2) version or higher? In my case I downgraded from 9.0.1 to 8.0.3 (or 8.0.2)  and this change fixed this problem. Unfortunately, I don't know why

Comment: For me, it ended up being that I had a call to app.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication() happening in my Startup config after API Route Mapping took place. I had to move that call to before API Route Mapping took place, and my 401 went away.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the very late response but if you enable full logging in IdentityServer it will pretty much tell you what the problem is.

Change

```
var options = new IdentityServerOptions
{
    Factory = factory,
};
```

to

```
var options = new IdentityServerOptions
{
  Factory = factory,                   
  LoggingOptions = new LoggingOptions
  {
      EnableWebApiDiagnostics = true,
      WebApiDiagnosticsIsVerbose = true,
      EnableHttpLogging = true,
      EnableKatanaLogging = true
  }
}
```

You'll then see an awful lot of great debugging information that tells you what is going wrong.

Comment: I did this already and my logging doesn't show me anything related to the 401 Unauthorized. The last thing it says is that it successfully validated my token request and returned token response. I never hit the breakpoint in my API Controller which I'm calling, the 401 is returned before that happens. I wish the logging had info on what is happening here, but for me it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

In your WebAPI configuration, in `IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions` you have incorrect value for property `Authority`. It has to be the base URI of your IdentityServer instance, i.e. `https://localhost/WebHostedId3`, and not just `localhost`, neither `localhost:443`.

Taken into account that IdentityServer3 requires TLS per default, then you'll need to specify `https` scheme and not just `http`.

So, as long as your IdentityServer base URI is `https://localhost/WebHostedId3`, then the correct setup will look like this

```
app.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(
    new IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions
    {
        Authority = "https://localhost/WebHostedId3",
        ValidationMode = ValidationMode.ValidationEndpoint,
        RequiredScopes = new[] { "api" }
    });
```