# IdentityServer3 - 401 Unauthorized when calling Identity API Controller

Tags: c#, api, authentication, oauth-2.0, identityserver3

I have a project which uses IdentityServer3 for Auth as a Service.

Recently I was tasked with creating a seamless experience for End-Users to edit their identity information.

I did this by creating an API Controller in my application which uses a HTTPClient to call another API Controller living in my IdentityServer project. It basically exposes the Identity management methods to the world, but "passes-through" any requests on to the IdentityServer Api.

All is well right up until I call the IdentityServer Api Controller. My breakpoint there is never hit, regardless of the presence of a "Authorize" attribute. I end up receiving a "401: Unauthorized" back from the IdentityServer Api controller.

I've tried to reuse the original request's Auth headers, but that didn't work. I also tried to find a "access_token" claim from my claim principle, but one wasn't found.

here is a code snippet:

```
            var httpClient = new HttpClient();

            // this didn't work - tried reusing the auth from the original request
            //httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = request.Headers.Authorization;

            // this didn't work either - "access_token" is not found 
            //httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", Caller.FindFirst("access_token").Value);
            var routePrefix = GetRoutePrefix();

            var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(
                       $"{routePrefix}/post",
                       new ObjectContent(typeof(TDObj), entity, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter()));

            return response;
```

I'm new to IdentityServer3 and OAuth and not sure what to do next. I tried creating a new scope for "identity" and tried to make it a required scope in my client application, but that didn't seem to do the trick. I know I'm missing some key piece of understanding here, but there is so much documentation for IdentityServer, I don't know where to begin and can't find anything specific to this need. I'm in the weeds! Can anyone help me understand what's going on here? Thanks!

Comment: I ended up trying to get an accesstoken and calling SetBearerToken() on my HttpClient. I successfully received the token but I'm still receiving the 401 before the breakpoint in my Identity Api Controller is hit. I'm checking my logs, but the last log entry ends with saying it successfully validated my token request and responded with the token, nothing about the 401 error is found in the logs. I found this similar post, but got nowhere with it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33480517/401-unauthorized-when-calling-web-api-using-identityserver3?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by following Scott Brady's answer here: [Identity Server and web api for user management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38236876/identity-server-and-web-api-for-user-management?rq=1)

However, his answer didn't immediately work for me. I had to make sure to make the call for UseIdentityServerTokenValidation to happen BEFORE api route mapping happened.

That being said, my original attempt to hi-jack the Authorization headers from the inbound HTTPRequest of my Front-End application worked, so I was able to remove any code requesting an access token and didn't have to SetBearerToken() on my HttpClient. Just this:

```
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = request.Headers.Authorization;
```